# Get All `typedef` JSDoc in TS Source File

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to convert a large js + JSDoc codebase to ts, and I would prefer to do as little of it by hand as possible. `ts-migrate` is ok, but it is very limited and doesn't really keep all the hard work we have done that is stored in the JSDoc comments.

I was trying to convert all `@typedef` JSDoc comments to `type` statements in ts, similar to how `@pram` tags would be inlined in their function or `@enum` tags could be used to convert their target object to enums. However, I can not find a way to extract all the `@typdef` declarations form a file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ju6xvy?file=index.js

Here is a playground that has a simple demo. I want to get and print out the `typedef` statement at the beginning of the source string using the ts API, and eventually I need to remove that comment and replace it with another statement, so some recursive solution that works (`visitEachChild` doesn't) would be best. Documentation is minimal for the internal compiler online, so any help is appreciated.